# Was Ender retrovirally altered?

Tags: enders-game

> It's possible, and implied, that Ender **may have been retrovirally altered** ...
>   *(from Aramis's answer to [Is Ender genetically-engineered?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/is-ender-genetically-engineered/2741#2741) )*

I don't recall any such implications in the books. **Was that implied, and if so, where?**

Comment: I see that Bean was, but never any implication of Ender who looks to have been at most part of a basic eugenics program of selective breeding.  I may be wrong, it's been a long while.

Comment: I added an answer to the linked question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/is-ender-genetically-engineered/43333#43333) it may have relevence for this

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find any mention of this in First Meetings.

But I did find a quote (Bean's thoughts to himself) in *Ender's Shadow* that could - **if read incorrectly** - be construed as implying this:

> They flipped a genetic switch in me and made me an intellectual athlete. I can get the ball into the goal from anywhere on the field. But knowing *when* to kick. Knowing how to forge a team out of a bunch of players. **What switch was it that was flipped in Ender Wiggin's genes?** Or is that something deeper than the mechanical genius of the body? Is there a spirit, and is what Ender has a gift from God? We follow him like disciples. We look to him to draw water from the rock. (*Ender's Shadow*, Chapter 21 - "Guesswork")

Now, this is just Bean specilating about Ender and not really implying genetic engineering - but he WAS in the same sentence talking about retroviral genetic alteration in himself as a point of comparison. So a casual reader might get confused.